# Replace part of a asp label value without replacing entire content in the label

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm passing some HTML codes as value to a asp:Label which contains div with unique ids and class names and inline JavaScript. I want to make changed or add extra div inside the label by replacing any particular character in the label string. How can I get this done?

Lets say I have the below HTML code as the value for the asp Label with ID `lblcode`, in the HTML code I have 3 div with content1, 2 and 3 inside a div lvl1container. I want to add a content 4 with HTML div tags by replacing the `++ADD_MORE++` with `<div id=\"lvl1_4>content4</div>++ADD_MORE++`.

```
Client side:
<asp:Label ID="lblcode" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtappend" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnappend" runat="server" Text="Append"/>

Server side:
string code = "<div id=\"lvl1container\">"+
   "<div id=\"lvl1_1\">content1</div>"+
   "<div id=\"lvl1_2\">content2</div>"+
   "<div id=\"lvl1_3\">content3</div>"+
   "++ADD_MORE++"+
"</div>";
lblcode.Text = code;
```

So instead of replacing the entire content of the label I want to search only for `++ADD_MORE++` and replace it with the value given inside the asp textbox `txtappend`. How can I get this done? thanks in advance.

Comment: And you want to that server side or client?

Comment: @iamdlm you mean get it done using c# or javascript? If then, either way would work for me.

Comment: I think you should be asking how to make a list that you can add items to, with ASP.Net or Javascript.  The way you are approaching this is not a good way to do it.

Comment: Yes, although you should consider @Archer observation

Comment: `.Replace("++ADD_MORE++", txtappend.Value)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the append button click, try the below code

```
protected void btnappend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(lblcode.Text);
    sb.Replace("++ADD_MORE++", $"<div>{txtappend.Text}</div>");
    sb.Append("++ADD_MORE++");

    lblcode.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```